# Error with DeadLetters

Tags: scala, akka

I encounter an error while running my project I cannot solve.

Here is my code:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.actor.ScalaActorRef
import akka.pattern.gracefulStop
import akka.util._
import java.util.concurrent._
import scala.Array._
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

sealed trait Message
case class Start() extends Message
case class Stop() extends Message
case class TickMessage() extends Message
case class ChangePeriodMessage(period: Int) extends Message

class Clock extends Actor {
    val period: Int = 500//change into var

    def active: Receive = {
        case TickMessage => {
            context.parent ! TickMessage
            context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(period milliseconds, self, TickMessage)
        }
        //case ChangePeriodMessage(p3riod) => period = p3riod
        case Stop =>
            println("Clock: stopping")
            context.unbecome()
    }

    def receive = {
        case Start => {
            println ("start")
            context.become(active)
            context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(period milliseconds, self, TickMessage)
        }
    }
}

class Gps extends Actor {
    val clock = context.system.actorOf(Props[Clock], name = "clock")
    def receive = {
        case Start => clock ! Start
        case TickMessage => println ("tick")
        case ChangePeriodMessage(period) => clock ! ChangePeriodMessage(period)
        case _       => println ("GPS: received unknown message")//delete
    }
}

object main extends App {
    val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("mySystem")
    val gps = system.actorOf(Props[Gps], name = "gps")

    gps ! Start
}
```

Then the error:

```
[INFO] [08/29/2014 11:02:28.479] [mySystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] 
[akka://mySystem/user] Message [TickMessage$] from Actor[akka://mySystem/user/clock#-
1170129640] to Actor[akka://mySystem/user] was not delivered. [1] dead letters 
encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 
'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Replicated mutiple times before stopping.
I am trying to have an actor send an heartbeat message, but the message goes to `DeadLetters`...

Comment: I guess `Clock` actor supposed to be a child of `Gps`? If so, you should create it like this `val clock = context.actorOf(Props[Clock], name = "clock")`.

Comment: I did not spot that one! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When/if the actor is stopped/restarted your scheduled message send will keep sending messages, since the actor is no longer available the actorRef that it got when you created the scheduled send will point to DeadLetters.

If you want to avoid getting messages sent to DeadLetter during shutdown you can add lifecycle hooks by overriding `postStop()` and `preRestart(...)` in your actor and make those cancel the `Cancellable` that you get back from scheduling events getting sent.

Alternatively you can turn logging of dead letters during shutdown off with config as the log entry says.